# Отсутствующий SelectedItem в ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть форма. Вот ее содержимое

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Col1}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Sum" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Col2}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Sum" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick"/>
</Grid>
```

Вот ее бэкграунд (оно же вьюха)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Output _selected;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Output> Col1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Output> Col2 { get; set; }
    public Output Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return _selected;
        }
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Selected));
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Col1 = new ObservableCollection<Output>
        {
            new Output {Name="name_1", Sum=1 },
            new Output {Name="name_2", Sum=2 },
            new Output {Name="name_3", Sum=3 },
            new Output {Name="name_4", Sum=4 }
        };

        Col2 = new ObservableCollection<Output>
        {
            Col1[2],
            Col1[3],
            new Output {Name="name_5", Sum=5 },
            new Output {Name="name_6", Sum=6 }
        };
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Selected = null;
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Запускаю, выделяю в левом листе первый айтем. Все норм. Выделяю в левом листе последний айтем (нэйм 4). Соответствующий айтем выделяется и во втором листе. Теперь выделяю во втором листе последний айтем...

Ожидалось, что при этом в левом листе выделение снимется, потому что данного айтема нет в привязанной коллекции. Но выделение остается. Почему?

**UPD:**

Но самое печальное оказалось даже не в этом, а в том, что при перемещении табом по листам (или мышкой, нажимая на уже выделенные визуально айтемы) свойство Selected не изменяется. Это будет видно, если привязать к нему заголовок окна.

```
Title="{Binding Selected.Name}"
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что такое работать вообще должно?

Comment: Это известная история: `ListBox` и его «коллеги» не очень интуитивно себя ведут, если SelectedItem привязывается к элементу, которого в списке нет.

Comment: То, что вы пишете в UPD, правильно, и так и должно быть. Есть разница между Selected и Focused. Таб переключает именно фокус, выделение при этом автоматически **не** следует за фокусом. Хуже того, выделенных элементов может быть много, а фокус один.

Comment: Я бы просто использовал два свойства во вьюмодельке, при изменении одного из них чистил другое. По моему будет вести себя так, как вам хочется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как при проблемах с биндингом - то он просто игнорируется, т.е. в данном случае не будет изменения селекта в листбоксе, если попытаться указать несуществующий в ItemsSource элемент.
Если приведенное автором вопроса поведение листбоксов действительно необходимо, то нужно делать 2 поля Selected, т.е. каждому листбоксу своё, и немного логики в блоках set. например переустановку или обнуление соседнего Select при необходимости  (ну и победить зацикливание установки этих полей друг из друга)

По поводу "самого печального" - думаю это просто следствие нарушенного биндинга.